# how to use winston to setup log in a sub directory instead of root directory?

Tags: node.js, path, winston

I want to setup logs for my `nodejs` project inside a directory named logs

as per documentation [here](https://github.com/flatiron/winston)

i am doing :

```
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'logs/mylogs.log' });
```

But it is doing nothing.

How do i achieve the same?

Comment: if the folder /logs folder doesn't exist, you'll need to create it first.

Comment: yeah logs folder already exist but still i am facing the issue..

Comment: What platform are you on? Linux, Windows, Mac?

Comment: I am on Mac OS X 10.9.3

Comment: and you expect your logs folder to be inside of your project folder, right?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Put the below code in your server file.

```
var winston = require('winston');
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var path = require('path');
var logDir = 'log'; // directory path you want to set
if ( !fs.existsSync( logDir ) ) {
    // Create the directory if it does not exist
    fs.mkdirSync( logDir );
}
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            colorize: 'all'
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({filename: path.join(logDir, '/log.txt')})
    ]
});
logger.info("Anything you want to write in logfile");
```

Comment: fs is a core module and does not need to be installed from npm.

Answer (score 2):

Winston provides option to set **dirname** when creating log file.

By default Winston creates directory to project root:

```
new transports.File({
  filename: 'errors.log',
  dirname: 'logs',
  level: 'error',
})
```

If you want your logs for example inside src directory:

```
new transports.File({
  filename: 'errors.log',
  dirname: './src/logs',
  level: 'error',
})
```

Full code example:

```
import { createLogger, transports, format } from 'winston'
const { timestamp, combine, json, errors } = format

const buildLogger = () => {
  return createLogger({
    format: combine(
      timestamp(),
      errors({stack: true}),
      json()
    ),
    defaultMeta: {service: "your-service"},
    transports: [
      new transports.File({
        filename: 'events.log',
        dirname: 'logs',
        level: 'info',
      }),
      new transports.File({
        filename: 'errors.log',
        dirname: 'logs',
        level: 'error',
      }),
    ]
  })
}

export default buildLogger
```

Answer (score -4):

You should use a relative path **(the dot and backslash)**:

```
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: './logs/mylogs.log' });
```